# Migrating MySQL database structure with foreign keys fails

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I am trying to set up a new testing server with a somewhat complex database structure by dumping the old database and importing it. But even though I use `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`, the import fails with `Can't create table 'DatabaseX.TableY' (errno: 150)`.

The referenced table probably doesn't exist yet, so I understand why it complains. But I just can't figure out how to reorder the dumpfile in such a way that the import works, or how to make MySQL ignore missing tables etc during import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh, I noticed that there was some remains from an earlier, botched migration. Dropped all databases, and then import worked.

Answer (score 0):

All the tables have to be created first before setting foreign key constraints on them.
You could use SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; before the create table functions and SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; after. or you could just try DISABLE KEYS and ENABLE KEYS as appropriate.

Comment: As I already noted, SET FOREIGN_KEYS_CHECK does not help. I have tried dumping using both mysqldump and MySQL Workbench.

Is there any tool that dumps the table structure and adds indexes and restraints as ALTER commands?